# setDateDisabled + start/end date break bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using the [bootstrap-datepicker from eternicode](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) and I'm against a strange behaviour.

When I try to use the [setDatesDisabled](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/stable/methods.html#setdatesdisabled) option on the fly with the default [startDate](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/stable/options.html#id6) and [endDate](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/stable/options.html#id5) option, the datepicker seem to freez and don't allow me to change the month any-more.

The strangest thing is a simple `alert()` just before the call of `setDatesDisabled` seem to correct the bug...

My final need is to add some disabledDate on the fly, using a function as a data provider

The simplified code :

```
        // enable the datepicker on fields
    $('.date-picker').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            startDate: '2016-04-01',
            endDate: '2016-08-15',
            datesDisabled: ['2016-04-21','2016-04-20','2016-04-13']
        })
        .on('show', function(ev){
            // @TODO check why bug here...
        // alert('hi'); // uncomment to patch bug
            $(this).datepicker('setDatesDisabled', ['2016-04-17','2016-04-16']);

        });
```

Check [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zj9sjspf/10/) to reproduce.

Does anyone face the same thing / have a work around to disable some date on the fly ?

I've already make [a bug report](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/1691) on the eternicode Github, as I think is may be an internal bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its most likely due to the fact that the datepicker `'show'` event fires multiple times as you navigate while the datepicker calendar is open.

Setting disabled dates while the callendar is already opened causes it to be recalculated and reloaded so it navigates back to the month with the currently selected date - this makes it impossible to navigate away from the page with the selected date (the half working scenario happens when there is no selected date).

Not sure if this is applicable in your scenario but this should work when you set the disabled dates only when calendar is not opened.

I changed

```
.on('show', function(ev){
```

to

```
$('.date-picker').on('click', function(ev){
```

and this seemed to work fine, see the updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zj9sjspf/11/

Second slightly "hackish" solution is that you could disable automatic `showOnFocus`, and manually check if the calendar is not opened + set the new disabled dates + trigger `show` manually when the field is being focused on. This is not the best way of doing this, but might be the way to go while you wait on replies on your bug report ;)

One way of doing this can be seen here:
https://jsfiddle.net/zj9sjspf/13/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zj9sjspf/12/ => the `on click` won't fire when you use TAB to change to the next field (as expected of `click`), so it not use my custom date... half soled only so :-/

Comment: I've tried something with `on focus` but it's the same as `show`, freez the datepicker u_u"

Comment: @Blag Yep, added a second solution that might suit you more

Comment: ok thanks +1, I'll wait until Monday before validate, if someone got a "legit" way to do it, but I'll go with the hackish version I think...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with `setEndDate` and `setStartDate` on the fly. The datepicker was broken and couldn't change month, year etc and solved it like this:

```
var setDatesDisabled = false;

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    // Whatever options
})
.on('show', function(e) {
    if (!setDatesDisabled) {
        $(this).datepicker('setDatesDisabled', ['2016-04-17','2016-04-16']); 
        setDatesDisabled = true;
    }
})
.on('hide', function(e) {
    setDatesDisabled = false;
});
```

The `show` event will only run when the datepicker opens and **NOT** as you navigate.